# Is there any command in MySQL that can help me skip certain data at a defined frequency?

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query (MySQL) as below:

`` SELECT DISTINCT `date`,`type` FROM `chart_data` WHERE `import_code` = 'XYZ' AND (`date` BETWEEN 'sdate' AND 'edate') ``

where sdate and edate are my start date and end date respectively. This will return all the dates starting from my start date till end date.

**My Requirement**: What I wanted was, if the date difference is within 1 year then all data should be retrieved but if the date difference is more than 1 year and less than 2 years then the data will be retrieved at an interval of 2 days (Example: 1 Jan 2018, 3 Jan 2018, 5 Jan 2018 and so on). Similarly, if the date difference is more than 2 year and less than 3 years then the data will be retrieved at an interval of 3 days (Example: 1 Jan 2018, 4 Jan 2018, 7 Jan 2018 and so on)

Is there any command in MySQL that can help me skip certain data at a defined frequency?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command or function which will give you that. You could try grabbing all data, assigning a row number and then finding the days you are interested in by using a timestampdiff in a mod calculation.
for example

```
select dte,ddiff
from
(
select timestampdiff(day,'2018-01-01','2018-01-02') + 1 ddiff
) d
cross join
(
select dte,@rn:=@rn + 1 rn
from dates , (select @rn:=0) r
) s
where s.rn % d.ddiff = 0 and 
        dte between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-10'
```

result

```
+------------+-------+
| dte        | ddiff |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 |     2 |
| 2018-01-03 |     2 |
| 2018-01-05 |     2 |
| 2018-01-07 |     2 |
| 2018-01-09 |     2 |
+------------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```